# How to get list of DataTables metadata used in SSAS DSV?

Tags: ssas, ssas-2012, database-metadata, dmv

I was wondering if there's a simple way to extract a list of all the tables description from the Data Source View at SSAS? I've been so far been playing around with this simple DMV-query to get the cube metadata:

```
SELECT * FROM $system.dbschema_tables
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'TABLE'
```

Which returns me a complete list of the tables but it's completely blank at DESCRIPTION despite the fact that I written in several of the DataTables Description field. Am I perhaps using the wrong rowset?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for the case if you are able to do it semi-manually:

1. You generates XMLA script for every SSAS Cube in the SSMS
2. Uses following XPATH query to collect the tables/views used in DSV of the cube: /Create/ObjectDefinition/Database/Cubes/Cube/Annotations/Annotation[*]/Value/dds/ddscontrol[*]/layoutobject/ddsxmlobj[not(boolean(./property[@name="Virtual"]))]/property[@name="LogicalObject"]/@value

P.S you can use websites like http://xpather.com to play around with the query on your XMLA
P.P.S result is returned in following format: <SchemaName>_<TableName>